# Create one object file for multiple files in directory

Tags: oop, object, lua, luajit

I have around 5 files(a.lua, b.lua, c.lua, d.lua, e.lua) in one directory say **dir_1**. Is it possible to create one object file for all the files in **dir_1**?

I want to use **dir_1** files in some other directory. What are the possible ways to do so? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean with: I want to use dir_1 files in some other directory?
And what is an object file in your opinion?

Comment: How do you use `a.lua`,... `e.lua`?  And how do you wish to use them as a single dir?  Give an example of code.

Comment: Do you mean `luac -o all_in_some_order.lub *.lua`?

Comment: suppose i have **dir_1** (a.lua,... e.lua) and **dir_2**  (x.lua,y.lua)  directories. I want to invoke functions defined in **dir_1**  (a.lua,... e.lua) inside **dir_2**  (x.lua).  It is possible by using  package.path.
My question is there any way to create one common object file for all the 5 files  **dir_1** (a.lua,... e.lua) so that i can invoke just by using require"object_file" in  **dir_2** (x.lua,y.lua) . Like in C language we create common library for multiple file and can invoke it using include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a composite compiled script. For example,

```
luac -o all_in_some_order.lub *.lua
```

I gave it a .lub extension for Lua Binary. Nonetheless, Lua treats binary and text scripts the same. Like a text script, the composite is just like a body, except that the composite is one or more function bodies run sequentially.

You could specify the order of execution on the command line, if necessary.

See `luac` for other options.

Note: your executables might be named like luac53.